# CNContactPickerDelegate didSelect not firing when searching

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift 3 app that uses a CNContactPickerViewController to let users select people from their contact list. I have implemented CNContactPickerDelegate with didSelect to pick up multiple selections using:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {}
```

This works great if the user picks one or more contacts from the list.  However, if they search, this function never fires.

If I remove this interface and put in the one for single selection:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: CNContact) {}
```

search and single selection from the list work fine.

If they are both present, the single select interface never fires.

I need to be able to allow the user to select one or more contacts from the list AND search. Any help would be appreciated.

Jeff

Comment: HII@jeff Dales.  Did you solve that? I am facing the same issue.